# PHP Syntax Error - Version 5.3.10

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is a syntax error in PHP version 5.3.10, Please anyone help me.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/videos',
                    array(
                        'description' => $description,
                        'title'       => $title,
                        'source'      => '@'.$file
                    )
                ))
                ->execute()
                ->getGraphObject()
                ->asArray();
```

Comment: We are not a community driven debugger.

Comment: "Please anyone help me". → Go forth and upgrade PHP.

Comment: what exactly is the syntax error?

Comment: Shouldn't be closed, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is valid syntax in PHP 5.4, but not in PHP 5.3. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().

So, either upgrade to PHP 5.4, or do this instead:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/videos', array(
    'description' => $description,
    'title'       => $title,
    'source'      => '@'.$file
));
$response = $request->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Before PHP 5.4, you couldn't dereference a newly-instantiated object in that way.

**Edit**

As @DanielWaghorn explained, the PHP SDK for Facebook requires PHP 5.4+. You'd get an explanatory error about this if it weren't for the syntax error. I'm still leaving my example above for others that have an issue with dereferencing a new object in PHP<5.4.0.

> It's also worth noting that the current version of the PHP SDK for Facebook requires PHP 5.4 or greater to work correctly anyway. Provided you didn't have this syntax error and the code run it would throw an exception stating that it requires a newer version of PHP.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the current version of the PHP SDK for Facebook requires PHP 5.4 or greater to work correctly anyway. Provided you didn't have this syntax error and the code run it would throw an exception stating that it requires a newer version of PHP.